# Import/Export option not found in messages app (4.1.2)

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean

I just upgraded my cell phone to android 4.1.2. And I was shocked to see that there is no import/export option in my messages app. While in 4.1.1 there was the option of import/export.

**My search for solution:** I have tried many other apps for messages too, they all lack the import/export feature.

I then tried a new ROM of same version, 4.1.2! But again same results.

**My Question:**

Is there a ROM issue, or 4.1.2 does not allow this feature to import/export?

**My cellphone:** I am using Qmobile A8. I have tried ROMs by INCPak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is transfer your SMS messages to another device or back them up, use an app like [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore)- that allows you to import / export / back up your SMS messages for posterity.

It also allows a user to selectively pick and choose which conversations you want to backup or restore.

Comment: Perfect..I would love to use this one! :) Thanks..